# Configure SKS editor to snap to grid

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

Is it possible to snap to grid from within the .sks editor?

I'd like to be able to make a tile game and create the world from within the .sks scene itself, but it doesn't seem possible to have the sprites that I place in the .sks scene snap to the grid.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

press shift while moving the sprite and it will snap to grid